# Problem with cut vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 10 p. 683:
[image: cut]

From what I see, the removal of `b` and its incident edges produces one subgraph and a lone vertex.  In contrast, the removal of `c` and `e` produces two subgraphs each.  How can `b` qualify as a cut vertex?

Comment: What is the def of "cut vertex" ? Removing.... the resulting subgraphi is disconnected. The removal of "b" and its three incident edges disconnect the graphi because vertex "a" is no more connected to the other part of the subgraph.

Comment: Definition of [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Graph) : a pair $G = (V, E)$, where $V$ is a set whose elements are called *vertices*, and $E$ is a set of two-sets (sets with two distinct elements) of vertices, whose elements are called *edges*."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you so much!